# Find the max and min value of $f(x,y)=3x-4y$ over $x^2+4y^2 \leq 13$

Tags: calculus, optimization

I am required to find the maximum and minimum values of $f(x,y)=3x-4y$
on the region $x^2+4y^2 \leq 13$?

Can anyone guide me how to do this kind of question?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Try the method of Lagrange Multipliers (e.g. Example 4): http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LagrangeMultipliers.aspx

Answer (score 2):

We do it in a calculus-free way. Consider the line $3x-4y=w$, as $w$ varies.  As $w$ changes, the line moves parallel to itself. When $w$ is large negative, the line will be far from our elliptical region.As $w$ increases, it will get closer, until it finally *touches* the boundary of the region. Then, as $w$ increases further, the line keeps passing through the region, until for suitable $w$ it again just touches the region.

So for the min/max values of $w$, we want the line $3x-4y=w$ to ne tangent to the ellipse. So the line and ellipse should meet in a double point. Thus
$$\left(\frac{4y+w}{3}\right)^2 +4y^2=13$$
has a double root. Equivalently, $52y^2+8wy+w^2-117=0$ has a double root.
The condition for this is that the discriminant is $0$. We obtain the equation
$$64w^2=(4)(52)(w^2-117)$$
This simplifies to $9w^2=9(13^2)$, giving $w=\pm 13$.

**Remark:** If we are in a calculus mood, we can note that the line $3x-4y=w$ has slope $\frac{3}{4}$. The slope $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of the tangent line to $x^2+4y^2=13$ at  $(x,y)$ is given by $2x+8y\frac{dy}{dx}=0$. So at the point of tangency we have $x=-3y$. Now we can solve for $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the constraint set is compact, hence a minimiser and a maximiser exist.

Also note that $f$ has non zero gradient everywhere, hence it has no local minimiser or maximiser. Consequently, the constraint **must** be active at
a minimiser or maximiser.

It follows that you need only look for a minimiser or maximiser on the set
$x^2+4 y^2 = 13$. You can use Lagrange multipliers for this.

**Alternative approach**:
Let $z=2y$, then the problem becomes
$\min \{ 3x-2z | x^2+z^2 \le 13 \}$
(and $\max$).

It should be clear from a picture that the solution must lie on the line through the origin in the direction $(3,-2)$, that is, the solution must have
the form $(x,z)=(3t,-2t)$ for some $t$. It is not too hard to check that
the minimising and maximising values of $t$ are $-1$ and $1$ respectively
and these correspond to costs of $\pm 13$.
Hence the extremisers in the original coordinates are
$(-3,1)$ and $(3,-1)$ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint-1**: Use Lagrange multipliers to solve it.

**Hint-2**: Try to find out the general equation of the ellipse $x^2+4y^2=13$. Now, compare that tangent equation with the given equation of the line, and try to find out the point where tangent touches the ellipse. There will be a quadratic equation in terms of $x$. After solving it you will find four points. Two of them give you the max and other two will be the min.